# MacOs "Window" MenuItem in Qt 6.5 QML

Tags: macos, qt, qml

I am writing a Desktop MacOS application in Qt 6.5 Qml Quick. As part of that, I would like to utilize the standard menubar, as it is taking up space, anyway. I see I can use the `Qt.labs.platform` `Menubar`, `Menu`, and `Menuitem` to place items on the standard MacOS menubar. I would like to use this functionality to add a Window menu item. On MacOS, it looks like there is a standard set of Window items, and I was wondering if there was a way to add this menu automatically. There do not appear to be any roles related to Window.  The standard set looks like this:

[image]

The roles  like `role: MenuItem.AboutRole` will move the about item to the applicaiton menu an change its text to the standard text. Also, adding "Edit" apparently automatically adds a menu item for "Emoji & Symbols" and Sometimes "Start Dictation..." (if we add menu items to it).

Is there a way to similarly automatically populate the standard Window MenuItem for "Window" parent item?

[image]

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import Qt.labs.platform

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MenuBar {
        id: menuBar

        Menu {
            id: fileMenu
            title: qsTr("File")

            MenuItem
            {
                id: appAboutApp
                text: "About.."
                role: MenuItem.AboutRole
            }

            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Zoom In")
                shortcut: StandardKey.ZoomIn
                onTriggered: zoomIn()
            }


            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Zoom Out")
                shortcut: StandardKey.ZoomOut
                onTriggered: zoomOut()
            }

        }

        Menu {
            id: editMenu
            title: qsTr("Edit")
            // ...
        }

        Menu {
            id: windowMenu
            title: qsTr("Edit")
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

[image]